# Why is there no docs on pandas.MultiIndex.map in version 0.24.2? does it relate to pandas.Index.map?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The docs of version 0.24.2 mentions nothing about `pandas.MultiIndex.map`. The last docs version has it is version 0.22. Version 0.24.2 only mentions `pandas.Index.map`
I am curious about them so I run them in ipython

```
In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '0.24.2'

In [3]: pd.MultiIndex.map
Out[3]: <function pandas.core.indexes.base.Index.map(self, mapper, na_action=None)>

In [4]: pd.Index.map
Out[4]: <function pandas.core.indexes.base.Index.map(self, mapper, na_action=None)>
```

and then `help(pd.MultiIndex.map)` and `help(pd.Index.map)` return the sam information.

Are they wrapper or decorator of `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index.map` ? and why version 0.24.2 docs has no reference at all about `pandas.MultiIndex.map`?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - realized that `.map` is a class method and inherited; updated the answer accordingly.

`pd.Index.map` and `pd.MultiIndex.map` are the same function. You can verify this:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.Index.map is pd.MultiIndex.map  # True
```

It seems that all indexes are subclasses of `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` (aka `pd.Index`) where the `map` function is defined. `pd.MultiIndex` has the same `map` function because it inherits it from `pd.Index` and doesn't override it.

I'm not sure about this, but it could even be the case that these *were* previously distinct functions (`pd.MultiIndex` overrode the method from `pd.Index`) and were only merged more recently (e.g. `pd.Index.map` was updated to be general enough for any type of index). That could explain why one is no longer mentioned in the docs but was previously.

Comment: could you explain further on `pd.Index`. Why does it turn into `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`? Version 0.21 also has the same behavior as 0.24.2  `pd.Index.map is pd.MultiIndex.map`  returning `True`. It means this implementation has existed for a while back, not changing recently. Version 0.21 docs also shows both `Index.map` and `MultiIndex.map`

Comment: `pd.Index` doesn't "turn into" `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`; it *is* `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`. But it would be a pain for you, as a user, to reference it that way every time. To make it easier for you, the devs imported it in `__init__.py` at the root of the project so that you can just reference `pandas.Index`. This is a common way that Python developers can keep the structure of the source code that they want (e.g. having the folders core, indexes, and base) without making it too onerous for users to access the most important classes